# Determining run-lengths of the elements of a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am attempting to count the number of times each number in a vector occurrs contiguously in the vector.

For example, given

```
vector = [8 8 8 7 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 3 5 3 2 2];
```

I want an output which will tell me two dimensional matrix where the first row contains the value of the vector, and the second row contains the run length for that value:

```
8   7   6   5   4   3   5   3   2
3   1   2   10  2   1   1   1   2
```

The actual matrix is larger in size. Is there a specific function which returns such values or are there any other ways I can resolve this challenge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Length Encoding in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059744/run-length-encoding-in-matlab)

Comment: Please emphasize run-length coding part in the question as it was really not obvious to me.

Comment: Thank you, question has been edited :). @mbschenkel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ind = [find(diff(vector)) numel(vector)];
result = [vector(ind); ind(1) diff(ind)];
```

Comment: thanks,
If using 'unique' then the result is not the same as the example above. 'unique' will count the number of each vector so that the result is not the same as the example above

Comment: Sorry. Your title was confusing. What you want is not what the title says. You want run-length encoding. I'll rewrite my answer

Comment: Try now. I suggest you rephrase the title to something like "Determining run-lengths in a vector"