# Find number of consecutive ones in binary array

Tags: arrays, matlab, run-length-encoding

I want to find the lengths of all series of ones and zeros in a logical array in MATLAB. This is what I did:

```
A = logical([0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]);
%// Find series of ones:
csA = cumsum(A);
csOnes = csA(diff([A 0]) == -1);
seriesOnes = [csOnes(1) diff(csOnes)];
%// Find series of zeros (same way, using ~A)
csNegA = sumsum(~A);
csZeros = csNegA(diff([~A 0]) == -1);
seriesZeros = [csZeros(1) diff(csZeros)];
```

This works, and gives `seriesOnes = [4 2 5]` and `seriesZeros = [3 1 6]`. However it is rather ugly in my opinion.

I want to know if there is a better way to do this. Performance is not an issue as this is inexpensive (`A` is no longer than a few thousand elements). I am looking for code clarity and elegance.

If nothing better can be done, I'll just put this in a little helper function so I don't have to look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an existing code for *run-length-encoding*, which does the (ugly) work for you and then filter out your vectors yourself. This way your helper function is rather general and its functionality is evident from the name `runLengthEncode`.

Reusing code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18490872/3139711):

```
function [lengths, values] = runLengthEncode(data)
startPos = find(diff([data(1)-1, data]));
lengths = diff([startPos, numel(data)+1]);
values = data(startPos);
```

You would then filter out your vectors using:

```
A = logical([0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]);
[lengths, values] = runLengthEncode(A);
seriesOnes = lengths(values==1);
seriesZeros = lengths(values==0);
```

Comment: I like this answer the most for its generality. I know I was originally seeking clarity and elegance, and the other answers have this as well, but I think the extra generality of this answer merits accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: To make the above RLE algorithm compatible both with row and with column vectors, one can change the first line of the function to `startPos = find(diff([data(1)-1; data(:)])).';`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
A = logical([0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]);
B = [~A(1) A ~A(end)];                %// Add edges at start/end
edges_indexes = find(diff(B));        %// find edges
lengths = diff(edges_indexes);        %// length between edges

%// Separate zeros and ones, to a cell array
s(1+A(1)) = {lengths(1:2:end)};
s(1+~A(1)) = {lengths(2:2:end)};
```

Answer (score 0):

This [`strfind`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) (works wonderfully with numeric arrays as well as string arrays) based approach could be easier to follow -

```
%// Find start and stop indices for ones and zeros with strfind by using
%// "opposite (0 for 1 and 1 for 0) sentients" 
start_ones = strfind([0 A],[0 1]) %// 0 is the sentient here and so on
start_zeros = strfind([1 A],[1 0])
stop_ones = strfind([A 0],[1 0])
stop_zeros = strfind([A 1],[0 1])

%// Get lengths of islands of ones and zeros using those start-stop indices 
length_ones = stop_ones - start_ones + 1
length_zeros = stop_zeros - start_zeros + 1
```