# Delete adjacent repeated terms

Tags: matlab, vector, duplicates, unique

I have the following vector `a`:

```
a=[8,8,9,9,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]
```

From `a` I want to delete all "adjacent" repetitions to obtain:

```
b=[8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

However, when I do:

```
unique(a,'stable')

ans =

     8     9     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
```

You see, `unique` only really gets the *unique* elements of `a`, whereas what I want is to delete the "duplicates"... How do I do this?

Comment: so did the answer help you?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not marking as answered.

Comment: sure I was wondering if it helped thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a run-length-encoding problem (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059744/run-length-encoding-in-matlab)). You can modify Mohsen's solution to get the desired output. (i.e. I claim no credit for this code, yet the question is not a duplicate in my opinion).

Here is the code:

```
a =[8,8,9,9,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]

F=find(diff([a(1)-1, a]));
```

Since `diff(a)` returns an array of length (length(a) -1), we want to add a value at the beginning (i.e the `a(1)`) to get a vector the same size as `a`. Here we subtract 1 so that, as mentioned by @surgical_tubing, the command `find` effectively finds it because it looks for non zero elements, so we want to make sure the value is non zero.

Hence `diff([a(1)-1, a])` looks like this:

```
  Columns 1 through 8

     1     0     1     0    -8     0     1     0

  Columns 9 through 16

     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0

  Columns 17 through 20

     1     0     1     0
```

Now having found the repeated elements, we index back into `a` with the positions found by `find`:

```
newa=a(F)
```

and output:

```
newa =

  Columns 1 through 8

     8     9     1     2     3     4     5     6

  Columns 9 through 10

     7     8
```

Comment: Looks great, I'd like to ask though is there any particular reason to use -1 when you append `a(1)-1`? I understand that it is to allow the recording of the first element.

Comment: There's nothing special about -1.  It's just needs to be any value that is NOT `a(1)` to cause diff to find it.