# Thresholding a signal using hysteresis to reduce noise

Tags: matlab, optimization, signal-processing, octave, noise-reduction

I'm using a simple thresholding for noisy data to detect zeros/edges in signals. Since the noise can be pretty strong, I'm using hysteresis to improve the results. While this helps a lot, it also slows down a lot. Is there a way to improve this, maybe even a better way to calculate this? Currently I'm using the straight-forward loop approach:

```
% generate a signal
t = linspace(0, 10, 1000);
y = sin(2 * pi * t); 

% constants
threshold = 0;
hyst = 0.1;

% thresholding
yth = zeros(size(y));
for i = 2:length(y)
    if yth(i - 1) > 0.5 
        yth(i) = y(i) > (threshold - hyst);
    else
        yth(i) = y(i) > (threshold + hyst);
    end 
end
```

In comparison to `yth = y > threshold` this is much slower.

Comment: Hi, this might help you: [Vectorized array operation which depends on previous array value](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/378557-vectorized-array-operation-which-depends-on-previous-array-value)

Comment: Hi, this actually helped a lot, thanks! You can formulate an answer, if you like, otherwise i can do it with the code i have now.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement (25% time reduction; only for large inputs; on R2017b) can be gained by precomputing both possibilities for `yth(i)`:

```
function yth = idea1()
  yth = false(size(y)); % change #1 - `false` vs `zeros`
  c1 = y > (th - hyst); % change #2 - precompute c1, c2
  c2 = y > (th + hyst);

  for k = 2:numel(y)
      if yth(k - 1) 
          yth(k) = c1(k);
      else
          yth(k) = c2(k);
      end 
  end
end
```

Usually, a big improvement can be gained by vectorization. To vectorize this problem we must understand the switching logic, so let us put it into words:

- Start from **Mode 2**.
- **Mode 1**: Take a value from `c1`. As long as `c1` contains `true` values - take those. When a `false` value is encountered switch to **Mode 2**.
- **Mode 2**: Take a value from `c2`. As long as `c2` contains `false` values - take those. When a `true` value is encountered switch to **Mode 1**.

So if we could find the transition locations, we are practically done.

After some trial and error, while I was *unable* to get rid of the loop in a way that improves performance, I did reach the conclusion that it was possible (`idea2`). Furthermore, looking at the [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)-encoded correct `yth`, I came up with some pretty good approximations for it (`idea3` and `idea4`) - though these will require tweaking for other inputs.

Perhaps somebody could use it to find a more clever implementation with fewer redundant computations. My full code is provided below. The RLE encoding algorithm was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18490872/3372061), and RLE decoding [from here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4955).

```
function q48637952
% generate a signal
t = linspace(0, 10, 1000).';
y = sin(2 * pi * t); 

% constants
th = 0;
hyst = 0.1;

%% Comaprison:
% Correctness:
R = {originalIdea(), idea1(), idea2()};
assert(isequal(R{:}));
% Runtime:
T = [timeit(@originalIdea,1), timeit(@idea1,1), timeit(@idea2,1)];
disp(T);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function yth = originalIdea()
  yth = zeros(size(y));
  for i = 2:length(y)
      if yth(i - 1) > 0.5 
          yth(i) = y(i) > (th - hyst);
      else
          yth(i) = y(i) > (th + hyst);
      end 
  end
end

function yth = idea1()
  yth = false(size(y)); % change #1 - `false` vs `zeros`
  c1 = y > (th - hyst); % change #2 - precompute c1, c2
  c2 = y > (th + hyst);

  for k = 2:numel(y)
      if yth(k - 1) 
          yth(k) = c1(k);
      else
          yth(k) = c2(k);
      end 
  end
end

function yth = idea2()
  c = [y > (th - hyst), y > (th + hyst)];
  % Using Run-length encoding:
  [v1,l1] = rlEncode(c(:,1));
  [v2,l2] = rlEncode(c(:,2));
  rle = cat(3,[v1 l1 cumsum(l1)],[v2 l2 cumsum(l2)]);
  % rle(:,:,2) is similar to rle(:,:,1) with small changes:
  %  - col1 is circshifted by 1 and 
  %  - col2 has the 1st and last elements switched
  newenc = reshape([rle(1:2:end,3,2), rle(1:2:end,3,1)].', [], 1);
  yth = rlDecode(rle(:,1,2), [newenc(1); diff(newenc(1:end-1))]);
end

function yth = idea3()
  % Approximation of yth, should be almost indistinguishable with high resolution
  yth = [0 0 repmat(repelem([1,0],50), 1, ceil(numel(y)/(2*50)) )].';
  % The amount of zeros at the beginning as well as the value "50" are problem-specific 
  % and need to be computed using signal-specific considerations
  yth = yth(1:1000);
end

function yth = idea4()
  % Another approximation
  yth = circshift(y > th, 1);
  % The value "1" is problem-specific
end

end % q48637952

%% RLE (de)compression:
function [vals, lens] = rlEncode(vec)
  J = find(diff([vec(1)-1; vec(:)]));
  vals = vec(J);
  lens = diff([J; numel(vec)+1]);
end

function vec = rlDecode(vals, lens)
  l = cumsum([ 1; lens(:) ]);
    z = zeros(1, l(end)-1);
    z(l(1:end-1)) = 1;
    vec = vals(cumsum(z));
end
```

Comment: `idea2` produces wrong result. For example `y = rand(1,1000)-rand(1,1000);`.

Comment: @rahnema1 Well, that's unfortunate. I only tested it on the OP's example input. Obviously, ideas 3&4 are completely inapplicable to that case as well.