# how can I divide a Matlab array to different regions?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array of `[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 ]`. how can I divide it to ranges which shows same numbers in one array in Matlab? I want to make **matrix B** which is:

```
B(1) = [1 1 1 1]; 
B(2) = [2 2 2] ; 
B(3)= [3 3 3];
B(4) = [1 1];
B(5) = [2 2].
```

Comment: What happened to the `3` and `2` in the middle? Shouldn't your array have 7 regions?

Comment: yes I should divide to 7 regions, but how?

Comment: What you're asking for is [run length encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+run+length+encoding), which is covered by a few other questions.

Comment: I read but I was not able to apply to my code

Answer (score 3):

This is basically [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), the difference being you want to break the vector up into each string of repeated values instead of producing pairs of `[value, nRepeats]` [as is typically desired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12059744/52738). Since your strings of repeated values have different lengths, you'll need to store them in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). Here's one way to do it, using [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), and [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
A = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 1 1 2 2];
nReps = diff([0 find(diff(A)) numel(A)]);
B = mat2cell(A, 1, nReps);
```

This works by first computing the element-wise differences in `A` with `diff`. Anywhere there is a non-zero result represents a change in the value, and the index location of these non-zeroes are found with `find`. Padding the ends with 0 and the length of vector `A` and applying `diff` again gives us the length of each string of values. The original vector `A` is then broken up into a cell array using `mat2cell` and these lengths.

Comment: @zahra: Clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

Set one variable as the original number, so a = array[1], then test if the next value is the same as the previous, have a counter variable attached to this. Once is it not, load into array B, and change value of that variable and do it again.

make B a 2d array

Or, look into the unqie function of matlab and use the indexes to fill B.

Comment: The only trick is that, since the regions have different numbers of elements, you'll want to put them into a cell array instead of a normal 2d array.

Comment: `unique` will not work, at least not directly, because there may be different runs of the same value